# Fastest way to make Negative numbers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, math, negative-number

Is there any Fastest way for this line?

```
ballAngelRadianVector = -ballAngelRadianVector;
```

and also this:

```
ballDegree = fee - ballDegree ;
```

Comment: Why do you think it's slow? [This isn't the bottleneck you're looking for](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo&feature=player_detailpage#t=22s)

Comment: I don't understand.. That's not fast enough?

Comment: .. it is fast , but maybe something better .. ; ] ,,

Comment: Better? It takes 1.4% of a second to set one million number to negative..

Comment: Lol, basically the answer is no. Sorry I couldn't be any more helpful. See my answer for a good tactic for checking speeds of mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can get faster than that.. See this quick check I did:

```
var i:uint = 0;
for(i; i<1000000; i++)
{
    var a:int = -i;
}

trace(getTimer()); //14
```

Answer (score 2):

i was actually wondering something similar strictly from curiosity (i know this is not the bottleneck of my application). my question is, is it easier to set a var to a negative of itself, or to multiply it by -1. i am wondering if this varies from CPU, OS, etc, but i ran the following test:

```
$number = rand(100000,999999999);
$iterations = 10000000;

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++)
    $number = -$number;

echo "time: ".(microtime(true)-$start)."\n";
//
$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++)
    $number = $number * -1;

echo "time: ".(microtime(true)-$start)."\n";
//
$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++)
    $number = -$number;

echo "time: ".(microtime(true)-$start)."\n";
//
$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++)
    $number = $number * -1;

echo "time: ".(microtime(true)-$start)."\n";
```

which produced the output:

```
time: 0.66124606132507 (-self)
time: 0.64714503288269 (*-1)
time: 0.66628909111023 (-self)
time: 0.65639805793762 (*-1)
```

so it looks like multiplying by -1 is consistently faster (by a negligible amount)